# Confused about the reference in Java

Tags: java

I am confused about why the value of `next` is not the same as the `root.children[0]`? In my understanding, `next` points to `root.children[0]`. Therefore, if the value of `root.children[0]` is changed, `next` should also change.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Node root = new Node();
        Node next = root.children[0];
        root.children[0] = new Node();
        System.out.println(root.children[0]);
        System.out.println(next);
    }

    public static class Node {
        Node[] children = new Node[1];
    }
}
```

output

```
MyClass$Node@e6ea0c6
null
```

Comment: `next` does not point to `root.children[0]`, it's a copy of `root.children[0]` and therefore references the same object as `root.children[0]` for as long as `root.children[0]` is not changed.

Comment: When you assigned root.children[0] to next, root.children[0] was null, and only later you assigned an object to root.children[0] hence both are not same

Comment: you assigned the value of that moment to next, and at that point, it was null. if you want that new Node() to be referred by next, you should move the Node next = root.children[0]; to after the root.children[0] = new Node(); line

Comment: This is very bad code!! Unless it is some sort of programming challenge, you should consider rewriting it. If that's the case (you would like a rewrite), Im happy to add an answer for you. Real world java code should never look like this code as it stands, however...

Comment: @vikingsteve Yes, this is an example from the coding challenge. I face the problem when trying to build a Trie structure.

Comment: Ok well the programming challenge is making things insanely complicated by adding a static `Node` array named `children`, which is initialised with size 1. It's complicated even more by instantiating `root` and `next`. You need to thing about order of static initialisation when solving this. Just read the other answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider it like this, I'll mark the object in memory as {} and the reference as ->
So you start by `next = root.children[0]`, at this time `root.children[0] -> null`, it points to nothing in memory, no object, so next -> null.

Then you do `root.children[0] -> {a new Node}` but next is still `next -> null` it doesn't point to the same object, it's not a shortcut to `root.children[0]`, it's NOT `next -> root.children[0] -> {a new Node}`, next points to **nothing**

If you had `root.children[0] -> {a new Node}`, and then do `next = root.children[0]`, then next would point `next -> {a new Node}`, but again if your do now `root.children[0] = new Node()` it will result in `root.children[0] -> {a newer Node}`
and next will **NOT** point to this newer node

When you assign a object's reference to a variable, that variable will not always point to the same address in memory, by doing `new Node()` you create a new object somewhere in memory and with = you tell a variable to point to that newly allocated object

Comment: So... the output of the program is something like `Node@a153fb40` and then `null`, right ?

Comment: Sorry, which program are you referring to?

Comment: of course ´MyClass.java´. (I had not seen the output in the OP question, now when I reread it I see the output there)

Answer (score 4):

Let's dissect this code line by line:

```
Node root = new Node();
```

You created a new `Node` object. This object has a `children` array of length 1. Since you have not assigned anything to `children` yet, the array contains the single element `null`.

```
Node next = root.children[0];
```

As I said, `children[0]` is null, so `next` is now null. Note that in this line, you *did not* make it so that `next` ***always*** points to the same thing as `children[0]`. You only made `next` point to the same thing as `children[0]` is pointing to *at that time*.

```
root.children[0] = new Node();
```

Now `children[0]` is being assigned a non-null value. Note that this does *not* change the value of `next`.

Comment: So `next` is still null at the end of execution, right?

Comment: @vikingsteve Yes. The value of a variable doesn't change until the programmer changes it. `next` is only set once (to null), and it will stay that way.

Comment: I do not accept your answer because I think @Blagoj Atanasovski helps me understand the difference between using `root.children[0]` in different scenarios. However, I still like your answer! Your answer is very inspiring, too. It's sad that I could not accept two answer :(

Comment: @LoveTW I respect your choice. I was just a little confused because for a second there, you didn't accept any answer, which is why I deleted my comment after you accepted the other one :).

Comment: @LoveTW i think both answers deserve an upvote. +1 from me :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `root.children[0]` just have reference not the object. So, You need to First add children to root node and then assign as I have changed into below code.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Node root = new Node();
        root.children[0] = new Node();
        Node next = root.children[0];
        System.out.println(root.children[0]);
        System.out.println(next);
    }

    public static class Node {
        Node[] children = new Node[1];
    }
}
```